# AnyDesk CMD to PS1

Tags: powershell, command-line, intune

Im trying to convert this to a .ps1 so i can run with intune, however cant seem to get it to work right.

Any ideas?

```
@echo off
cmd for /f "delims=" %%i in ('"C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDeskMSI\AnyDeskMSI.exe" --get-id') do set ID=%%i 
echo AnyDesk ID is: %ID%
pause
```

The idea is it will put the ID, after that i can manipulate it no worries

Comment: I can get it to run using the following:
> $id = cmd.exe /c "test.bat"

Where test.bat is the above, but this means i have a need for 2 files to do a simple task,

Comment: You can run virtually any ```*.exe``` in the console as long as you properly define it with all it needs. No need for the .bat/.cmd, etc. at all. You can see this directly via this MS docs article --- [PowerShell- Running Executables - TechNet Articles - United States (English) - TechNet Wiki](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx) ---  and by looking at the powershell.exe help/ ```powershell /?``` for examples.

Comment: `$id = & "C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDeskMSI\AnyDeskMSI.exe" --get-id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDeskMSI\AnyDeskMSI.exe' --get-id | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining the parts.

Comment: @RohitGupta `&` is a call operator (see https://ss64.com/ps/call.html).  `|` is a pipeline (see: https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-pipeline.html).  In each Pipeline, the `$_` variable is created to access the current pipeline.  Using `ForEach-Object` is just a trick to get that pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment:

```
powershell /?

PowerShell[.exe] [-PSConsoleFile <file> | -Version <version>]
    [-NoLogo] [-NoExit] [-Sta] [-Mta] [-NoProfile] [-NonInteractive]
    [-InputFormat {Text | XML}] [-OutputFormat {Text | XML}]
    [-WindowStyle <style>] [-EncodedCommand <Base64EncodedCommand>]
    [-ConfigurationName <string>]
    [-File <filePath> <args>] [-ExecutionPolicy <ExecutionPolicy>]
    [-Command { - | <script-block> [-args <arg-array>]
                  | <string> [<CommandParameters>] } ]


EXAMPLES
    PowerShell -PSConsoleFile SqlSnapIn.Psc1
    PowerShell -version 2.0 -NoLogo -InputFormat text -OutputFormat XML
    PowerShell -ConfigurationName AdminRoles
    PowerShell -Command {Get-EventLog -LogName security}
    PowerShell -Command "& {Get-EventLog -LogName security}"
```

It's the last two sample entries that you should target for your use case.

If you are to do this in a PowerShell Script, then you'd wrap that command in a Start-Process code block.

```
Get-Help -Name Start-Process -Examples

NAME
    Start-Process
    
SYNOPSIS
    Starts one or more processes on the local computer.
    
    
    ----- Example 1: Start a process that uses default values -----
    
    Start-Process -FilePath "sort.exe"
    
    
    ----------------- Example 2: Print a text file -----------------
    
    Start-Process -FilePath "myfile.txt" -WorkingDirectory "C:\PS-Test" -Verb Print
    
    
    ---- Example 3: Start a process to sort items to a new file ----
    
    $processOptions = @{
        FilePath = "sort.exe"
        RedirectStandardInput = "TestSort.txt"
        RedirectStandardOutput = "Sorted.txt"
        RedirectStandardError = "SortError.txt"
        UseNewEnvironment = $true
    }
    Start-Process @processOptions
    
    This example uses splatting to pass parameters to the cmdlet. For more information, see about_Splatting (../microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting.md).
    ------- Example 4: Start a process in a maximized window -------
    
    Start-Process -FilePath "notepad" -Wait -WindowStyle Maximized
    
    
    ------- Example 5: Start PowerShell as an administrator -------
    
    Start-Process -FilePath "powershell" -Verb RunAs
    
    
    ----- Example 6: Using different verbs to start a process -----
    
    $startExe = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo -Args PowerShell.exe
    $startExe.verbs
    
    open
    runas
    runasuser
    
    The example uses `New-Object` to create a System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo object for PowerShell.exe , the file that runs in the PowerShell process. The Verbs property of the 
    ProcessStartInfo object shows that you can use the Open and RunAs verbs with `PowerShell.exe`, or with any process that runs a `.exe` file.
    -------- Example 7: Specifying arguments to the process --------
    
    Start-Process -FilePath "$env:comspec" -ArgumentList "/c dir `"%systemdrive%\program files`""
    Start-Process -FilePath "$env:comspec" -ArgumentList "/c","dir","`"%systemdrive%\program files`""
```

For example, calling cmd.exe and getting it's process Id.

```
Start-Process 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe' -PassThru
# Results
<#
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
     18       5     1532       2536       0.00   7956   1 cmd 
#>

# Or
Start-Process 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe' -PassThru | 
Select-Object -Property Id
# Results
<#
  Id
  --
2556
#>

# Or 

(Start-Process 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe' -PassThru).Id
# Results
<#
8996
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

To get the ID, you could execute:

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDeskMSI\AnyDeskMSI.exe' --get-id | Out-String
```

To capture the version in the `version` variable:

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDeskMSI\AnyDeskMSI.exe' --get-id | Tee-Object -Variable version
```

## Explanation

`&` is a call operator<sup>1</sup>

To capture the output of the `AnyDesk.exe` command, AnyDesk provided the batch script.  When running the executable on its own in the console, it doesn't look to output anything.  The reason isn't clear (unless we inspect their executable), but we can capture its output by using a pipeline.

<sub><sup>1. [Call operator - Run - PowerShell - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html)</sup></sub>